# How to measure FWHM and Peak value? (PYTHON)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, gaussian

There is a `dataframe` with '**df.groupby('ID')**'. I want to know the **FWHM** and **peak value** after **Gaussian fitting**.
Since 'ID' ranges from 1 to 144, 144 FWHM and 144 peak values should be output.
What should I do?
please help me